# Sql many id in one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

**STUDENT** table

```
ID | Name | Subject |
1  | foo  | 1,2,3   |
```

**SUBJECT** table

```
ID | Subject_name |
1  | Math         |
2  | Science      |
3  | History      |
```

I  tried this one

```
"SELECT * FROM student LEFT JOIN subject ON student.id = subject.id"
```

But their is an error

what I expected would be to get all subject_name in student table

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to find the value within the range and [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to return back the rows in comma separated value.

```
SELECT  s.id, s.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.Subject_name)
FROM    student s
        INNER JOIN subject t
            ON FIND_IN_SET(t.ID, s.subject)
GROUP BY s.id, s.Name
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53e7a/2).

However, consider also changing the schema of your table as currently it's not a desirable design.

Comment: but can I change the name of GROUP_CONCAT(t.Subject_name) for json_encode?

Comment: @user3793272 You should post a new question if you want JSON output.  Your answer is contained within the responses below your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry I just reached a limit to ask a question thats why im asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM subject t1
INNER JOIN student t2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.ID, t2.Subject) > 0
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

Note that `FIND_IN_SET` is not a function which engenders the best database design, because in general CSV data is not well suited to a database table.  That being said, you might want to consider breaking out the subjects in the `student` table into separate rows.

Comment: but can I change the name of GROUP_CONCAT(t.Subject_name) for json_encode?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create one more table which will connect `student` table and `subject` table e.g. `student_subject` which will consist of these fields: `id, student_id, subject_id`; and you should remove the `subject` field from `student` table.

**Select query:**

```
SELECT * /* fields you need */
FROM student
LEFT JOIN student_subject ON student.id = student_subject.student_id
LEFT JOIN student_subject ON subject.id = student_subject.subject_id
```

Answer (score -1):

To get all subject names from subject table for students you need to use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) and [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) functions in MySQL.

```
SELECT  a.id, a.Name, a.Subject,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.Subject_name ORDER BY b.id) SubjectName
FROM    student a
        INNER JOIN SUBJECT b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.Subject) > 0
GROUP   BY a.id
```

You can check my demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca06c/9)

Comment: but can I change the name of GROUP_CONCAT(t.Subject_name) for json_encode?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to separate values return in subject name to an array in you code and then you can use json_encode() on that array. If this is what your case is.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one:
      select t.subject_name from student s , subject t on s.id = t.id